# How to prevent Angular dnd-list draggable element from adding dragover class to Angular ng-f-upload dropzone

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

I am using Angular drag-and-drop-lists [see here](https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists) with Angular ng-file-upload [see here](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)

Problem:

When I drag to reorder the list item if I hover over the textarea (ng-file-upload dropzone) the dragover class is added to the dropzone.

How do I prevent the draggable element from dnd-list from triggering the drag over the ng-file-upload dropzone

Sample code

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<ul dnd-list dnd-drop="">
    <li ng-repeat="item in list"
        dnd-draggable="null" 
        dnd-callback="onDrop()">
      {{item.title}}
    </li>
  </ul>

<div ngf-drop="uploadMe($files,list.id)" 
ngf-drag-over-class="'dragover'" 
ngf-multiple="true" 
ngf-drag-over-class="{accept:'fileDragOver', reject:'textDragOver'}">
  <textarea  class="form-control"  ng-model="chatbox"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use `ngf-drop-disabled=true` if you don't want the element to be a drop zone.

Comment: Thank you danial, but the textarea needs to be a dropzone for all file types except browser element drag ghost image

Answer (score 1):

For this you've to use **dnd-type="xxx"** where **dnd-allowed-types** decides what type of item should be dropped.

```
<ul dnd-list="containers"
dnd-allowed-types="['container']"
dnd-external-sources="true"
dnd-dragover="dragoverCallback(index, external, type, callback)"
dnd-drop="dropCallback(index, item, external, type)">
<li ng-repeat="container in containers"
    dnd-draggable="container"
    dnd-type="'container'"
    dnd-effect-allowed="copyMove"
    dnd-moved="containers.splice($index, 1)"
    dnd-callback="container.items.length">
    <div class="container-element box box-blue">
        <h3>Container (effects allowed: {{container.effectAllowed}})</h3>
        <ul dnd-list="container.items"
            dnd-allowed-types="['item']"
            dnd-horizontal-list="true"
            dnd-external-sources="true"
            dnd-effect-allowed="{{container.effectAllowed}}"
            dnd-dragover="dragoverCallback(index, external, type)"
            dnd-drop="dropCallback(index, item, external, type)"
            dnd-inserted="logListEvent('inserted at', index, external, type)"
            class="itemlist">
            <li ng-repeat="item in container.items"
                dnd-draggable="item"
                dnd-type="'item'"
                dnd-effect-allowed="{{item.effectAllowed}}"
                dnd-dragstart="logEvent('Started to drag an item')"
                dnd-moved="container.items.splice($index, 1)"
                dnd-dragend="logEvent('Drag operation ended. Drop effect: ' + dropEffect)">
                {{item.label}}
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Example [demo](https://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/advanced)